# Calling componentWillMount every time focused page in react native

Tags: react-native, react-redux, components, react-navigation

I want call the componentWillMount every time that I focused a page. I using react-redux and react-navigation.

With react-navigation I use `import { withNavigationFocus } from 'react-navigation';` to detect if the page was active but when I call componentDidMount there ara a few seconds that I see old view. Is for this I want calling componentWillMount instead of componentDidMount when page focused.

This is my code:

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
       this.props._loading(true);
    }

    omponentDidMount() {

    const { navigation } = this.props;
    this.focusListener = navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {

        this.setState({loading: 0});

        this.props._loading(true);

        Api.get('s?type=Featured')
        .then( response => {
          if (response.profiles){
            this.setState({featured_users: response.profiles, loading: this.state.loading + 1});
          }
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          this.props._loading(false);
        });

        Api.get('s?type=Top')
        .then( response => {
          if (response.profiles){
            this.setState({featured_top: response.profiles, loading: this.state.loading + 1});
          }
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          this.props._loading(false);
        });
     });

  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Remove the event listener
    this.focusListener.remove();
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading >= 4){
      this.props._loading(false);
    }
    return (
       ...
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    user: state.reducerUser,
    loading: state.reducerGeneral
});

mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    _loading: loading => {
      dispatch(actionLoading(loading));
    },
    updateUser: user => {
      dispatch(actionUser(user));
    },
  }
}


export default withNavigationFocus(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeScreen));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this inside your componentWillMount and whatever you write inside your addListener , it will be executed everytime:

```
this.focusListener = this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
      // The screen is focused

      this.getData();
    });
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I didn't understand it correctly.

Even so, if I go to the next page and then back, I still see the old page for a few moments. Any ideas to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: thats because that action is async. if you want to explicitly start afresh a new page, try  navigation.push({screen:}) instead of navigation.navigate({scree

Comment: and do upvote if you found my answer to be helpful to you :)